# TensorFlow Probability: how to do sample weighting with log_prob loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I'm using TensorFlow probability to train a model whose output is a `tfp.distributions.Independent` object for probabilistic regression. My problem is that I'm unsure how to implement sample weighting in the negative log likelihood (NLL) loss function.

I have the following loss function which I believe does not use the `sample_weight` third argument:

```
class NLL(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    ''' Custom keras loss/metric for negative log likelihood '''

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        return -y_pred.log_prob(y_true)
```

With standard TensorFlow loss functions and a dataset containing `(X, y, sample_weight)` tuples, the use of `sample_weight` in the loss reductions summations is handled under the hood. How can I make the sum in `y_pred.log_prob` use the weights in the `sample_weight` tensor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem as posted in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/1461#issuecomment-964505994).

My problem was caused by the fact that my model outputs a `tfp.Independent` distribution, which means the `log_prob` is returned as a scalar sum over individual `log_prob`s for each element of the tensor. This prevents weighting individual elements of the loss function. You can get the underlying tensor of `log_prob` values by accessing the `.distribution` attribute of the `tfp.Independent` object - this underlying distribution object treats each element of the loss as an independent random variable, rather than a single random variable with multiple values. By writing a loss function that inherits from `tf.keras.losses.Loss`, the resulting weighted tensor is implicitly reduced, returning the weighted mean of `log_prob` values rather than the sum, e.g.:

```
class NLL(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    ''' Custom keras loss/metric for weighted negative log likelihood '''

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):

        # This tensor is implicitly reduced by TensorFlow
        #     by taking the mean over all weighted elements
        return -y_pred.distribution.log_prob(y_true) * sample_weight
```